# Nupic Installation Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu-13.04, nupic

I am having a heck of a time installing NUPIC on ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso [within Exsi 5.1].

I've followed the instructions on https://github.com/numenta/nupic/wiki/Install-Nupic-on-ubuntu-13.04.  The install fails at:

```
pip install -r external/common/requirements.txt
```

with the following error:

```
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/asteval': Permission denied
```

It works if I use sudo pip install... but just fails on

```
$NUPIC/build.sh
```

I also had to add

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

to even get it to the "pip install..." point.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Neil

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the report. I've [created a ticket](https://github.com/numenta/nupic/issues/536) to address this installation issue.

Neilg, please try these instructions: https://github.com/numenta/nupic/wiki/Installing-NuPIC-on-Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to install nupic.

I was following these instructions:
https://github.com/numenta/nupic/wiki/Running-Nupic-in-a-Virtual-Machine

The problem you may be facing is that your user does not have read/write access to the /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/asteval folder.  You can use the chown command to change that folders ownership to the user you want and give that user read/write access.

With regards to the above instructions, I installed using sudo but failed to realize that the environment variables for root were different than the environment variables for the user I created to install nupic.

Hope this helps,

VS

Comment: The problem is that certain python packages such as dateutils is already installed in ubuntu. You will have to remove them manually before using pip or else pip will try to remove the original package before reinstalling it. This leads to a permission denied error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you may be facing is that your user does not have read/write access to the /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/asteval folder. You can use the chown command to change that folders ownership to the user you want and give that user read/write access.

YOU NEED TO ADD THE OPTION --user after pressed commands